# Joomla Intro Image hover/ overlay effect

Tags: html, css, joomla

Does anyone know how to get an hover/ overlay effect on the article intro image in Joomla (3.6.3). The intro image is inserted in the intro image field in articles and it renders the following HTML:

```
<article class="uk-article" data-permalink="">  
    <a href="" title="">
        <img src="/domain/images/intro_image.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <h1 class="uk-article-title">
                <a href="" title=""></a>
            </h1>
            <p></p>
            <p></p> 
</article>
```

CSS

```
.start .uk-article img:hover{
    background:url(triangle2.png);
}
```

I am trying to get the article intro image to change to an png image while hovering the article image...

Comment: Do you want the image to change or just to show another image (with transparent background) on top of that?

Comment: I want to show an image (with transparent background) on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by the "overlay" an icon on top of an image, you can do something like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNNyMB):

HTML

```
<div class="intro-image">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3247/nature-forest-industry-rails.jpg?h=350&auto=compress" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.intro-image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.intro-image:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url("http://orig15.deviantart.net/3967/f/2014/046/c/f/simplistic_play_icon__ico__png__by_micahpkay-d6opha8.png");
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

EDIT: You can exchange the `.intro-image` for an anchor `a` tag so it fit's your example without need for edit of the HTML.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to add an div around the rendered img tag because the image is rendered from a field named 'intro image' in an article in Joomla.. Any suggestions how get the div tag around the img tag in Joomla?

Comment: then use the anchor tag instead of the div:

`.uk-article > a:hover::before`

Comment: It did not work either.. However I found a file named article.php which I edited. I added a div with some overlay classes from uikit around the img tag and that did work.

Comment: On [codepen](http://codepen.io/tomasblazek/pen/wogBpR) it worked just fine.